# Detect Fake CLicks and Impressions Ads Project

Tags: ip, ads

I am creating a mobile ads project and I need to detect real ip/user_agent/os and all that stuff. I am able to track them down but my problem is I will give the publisher php code and will detect everything on their servers and then send a POST request to my server to store data but since I am giving the code to them they can modify it and send fake IP/os/user agent and impressions to earn more.

I can't encrypt my code. Can any one answer with best solution to stop this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it

i am storing everything in cookies now so will be bit harder for publishers to flood